# Lattice vector size reduction

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-lattices

Let $L$ be a full rank lattice in $\mathbb Z^{n}$.
For a large real number $K$, how can we make the vector in $L$ whose euclidean norm is small than $K$?
I thought that I can find vectors easily in $\mathbb R$-span, but it is hard to find a vector in a lattice.